# Object generator for configurations

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The data I am getting is an array of objects such as :

```js
[
  {
    id: 0,
    config: false
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    config: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    config: false
  },
  {
    id: 3, 
    config: false
  }
]
```

I want to take this object and have some type of algorithm to make configurations into new objects like

```js
[
  {
    id: 0,
    config: false
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    config: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    config: false
  },
  {
    id: 3, 
    config: false
  }
]

[
  {
    id: 0,
    config: false
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    config: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    config: true
  },
  {
    id: 3, 
    config: false
  }
]
```

and so on... I just need one config to be true and all the others should be false. Any help would be appreciated I've been tearing my hair out from this. ES6 is also an option.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) for it.

```js
function* getParts(array) {
    var i = 1 << array.length;

    while (i--) {
        yield array.map((o, j) => Object.assign({}, o, { config: !(i & 1 << j) }));
    }
}

var array = [{ id: 0, config: false }, { id: 1, config: false }, { id: 2, config: false }, { id: 3, config: false }];

console.log([...getParts(array)]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is great. How would I be able to just generate the configurations with only one true at all times?

Comment: so you need only four arrays?

Comment: From your answer I think I got what I needed thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var object = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
  object [i] = {
    "id": i,
    "config": false
  };
}

// Algorithm
for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i ++) {
  var clone = makeClone (object);
  clone [i].config = true;
  console.log (clone);   
}

function makeClone (object) {
  var tmp = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i ++) {
    tmp [i] = {};
    var objectKeys = Object.keys (object [i]);
    for (var j = 0; j < objectKeys.length; j ++) {
      var key = objectKeys [j];
      tmp [i][key] = object [i][key];
    }
  }

  return tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. Suppose you need change config field with id = 1. Try this:

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: 0,
    config: false
  },
  ...
];

const newArr = arr.map(item => {
  if (item.id === 1) {
    item.config = true;
  }

  return item;
});
```

**Update**
Look at my jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/smhfanda/jwamLq01/